# Playing a video file in Pyglet

Tags: python, video, pyglet

Here is my code:
works well, it finds all the video files in the working directory, and then at user choice play that video. the problem is how I could close the video after 15 seconds?

```
import time
import fnmatch
import os
import pyglet
file_list=[]
for file in os.listdir('.'):
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(file, '*.mp4'):
        file_list.append(file)
        print(file_list)


a=int(input('which file ?'))
for i in range(len(file_list)):
    if a==i:
        Filename= (file_list[i])

print(Filename)

vid_path=str(Filename)
print(vid_path)
vidPath = vid_path
window= pyglet.window.Window()
player = pyglet.media.Player()
source = pyglet.media.StreamingSource()
MediaLoad = pyglet.media.load(vidPath)
player.queue(MediaLoad)
player.play()

@window.event
def on_draw():
    if player.source and player.source.video_format:
        player.get_texture().blit(50,50)
        
pyglet.app.run()
time.sleep(15)        
print('closing sir')
player.delete()  #this was for cosing video but didn't work, don't give any error.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do the below before `pyglet.app.run` (app run is a blocking call which is why your other code doesn't work):

```
def delete_player(dt):
    player.delete()

pyglet.clock.schedule_once(delete_player, 15)
```